# How to use Amazon MWS to indicate two different shipping times on items?

Tags: e-commerce, amazon-mws

I have a bit of a unique problem here. I currently have two warehouses that I ship items out of for selling on Amazon, my primary warehouse and my secondary warehouse. Shipping out of the secondary warehouse takes significantly longer than shipping from the main warehouse, hence why it is referred to as the "secondary" warehouse.

Some of our inventory is split between the two warehouses. Usually this is not an issue, but we keep having a particular issue. Allow me to explain:

Let's say that I have 10 red cups in the main warehouse, and an additional 300 in the secondary warehouse. Let's also say it's Christmas time, so I have all 310 listed. However, from what I've seen, Amazon only allows one shipping time to be listed for the inventory, so the entire 310 get listed as under the primary warehouse's shipping time (2 days) and doesn't account for the secondary warehouse's ship time, rather than split the way that they should be, 10 at 2 days and 300 at 15 days.

The problem comes in when someone orders an amount that would have to be split across the two warehouses, such as if someone were to order 12 of said red cups. The first 10 would come out of the primary warehouse, and the remaining two would come out of the secondary warehouse. Due to the secondary warehouse's shipping time, the remaining two cups would have to be shipped out at a significantly different date, but Amazon marks the entire order as needing to be shipped within those two days.

For a variety of reasons, it is not practical to keep all of one product in one warehouse, nor is it practical to increase the secondary warehouse's shipping time. Changing the overall shipping date for the product to the longest ship time causes us to lose the buy box for the listing, which really defeats the purpose of us trying to sell it.

So my question is this: is there some way in MWS to indicate that the inventory is split up in terms of shipping times? If so, how?

Any assistance in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No.**

There is no way to specify two values for `FulfillmentLatency`, in the same way as there is no way to specify two values for `Quantity` in stock. You can only ever have one inventory with them (plus FBA stock)

Longer answer: **You could.**

Sign up twice with Amazon:

- "MySellerName" has an inventory of 10 and a fulfillment latency of 2 days
- "MySellerName Overseas Warehouse" has an inventory of 300 and a fulfillment latency of 30 days

I haven't tried by I believe Amazon will then automatically direct the customer to the best seller for them, which should be "MySellerName" for small orders and "MySellerName Overseas Warehouse" for larger quantities.